# Adjust biblatex-chicago's @jurisdiction number field text and stop abbreviating months

Tags: biblatex-chicago, legal-style

So I've been searching for a biblatex style which let's me footnote cite legal materials properly. I would've used OSCOLA, but unfortunately that's mostly limited to the English-speaking common law jurisdictions. So instead I've opted for using the biblatex-chicago package which has custom entries for legal materials which adhere to Bluebook citation standards.

Now I've run into two things I'd like to change. First, I'd like to adjust the @jurisdiction number field so that it says "Case no." instead of "No." in front of the number field's input. Second, I'd like to stop the abbreviation of the months.

Example footnote:

[image: Example footnote]

Example `.bib` entry:

```
@jurisdiction{const_latvia_2012,
    number = {2012-06-01},
    note = {clause 7.2},
    location = {{Constitutional Court of the Republic of Latvia}},
    date = {2012-11-01},   
    url = {https://www.satv.tiesa.gov.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2012-06-01_Spriedums.pdf}   
}
```

Kind regards,

Rens

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` is a pretty complex style (because the CMS requirements are very complex and not always particularly algorithm friendly): Even seemingly small changes may need lots of code. Note also that things like the date format are likely global, i.e. apply to all (similar) dates typeset by `biblatex` (also for other entry types). It may not always be easy to change them just for one type (and the question is if you really want that anyway).

Comment: That all said, you can massively increase your chance of getting a good answer if you provide a compilable example document that reproduces the status quo. As your question stands now people trying to help you will have to whip up their own document and have to tediously re-type your `.bib` entry manually. Help those trying to help you by giving them the code you already have in a simple-to-use way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!